# Store functions in List or Array in Unity3D

Tags: c#, methods, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am trying to load different functions without using to much if statements (C#). I tried using Lists, but to Unity throws an exception by using `Action`. 
I found a nice solution for c# here:

```
var methods = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
          {
              {"method1", () => method1() },
              {"method2", () => method2() }
          };

methods["method2"]();
```

Same problem here with the `Action`

I imported

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `System.Collections.Generic` for the `Dictionary`, you also need to import `System` for the `Action`.

Add `using System;` to the top of your file.

In general, look up the type on MSDN to see its full namespace. In this case, the MSDN page for the [Action delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) indicates that its namespace is "System". As such, you'll either have to add a `using System;` directive at the top of your code or include the full namespace in your code. So for example, you could rewrite your code above without `using` directives if you have:

```
var methods = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Action>()
      {
          {"method1", () => method1() },
          {"method2", () => method2() }
      };

methods["method2"]();
```